# Error creating menu with Angular - Material

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am trying to make the right side menu as attached in my Angular project. There is no problem in the Home and Photo menus, the menu will not open. However, I'm having trouble with Admin menu. I'm planning to open 2 submenus when we click on the Admin menu, but I couldn't.

I can access that page when I type admin/person in the url, but I couldn't add it to the bottom of the menu, can you help?

```
<li routerLinkActive="active" *ngFor="let menuItem of menuItems" class="{{menuItem.class}} nav-item">
  <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="[menuItem.path]">
    <i class="material-icons">{{menuItem.icon}}</i>
    <p>{{menuItem.title}}</p>
  </a>
</li>
```

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

declare const $: any;
declare interface RouteInfo {
  path: string;
  title: string;
  icon: string;
  class: string;
  children: any;
}
export const ROUTES: RouteInfo[] = [
  { path: '/home', title: 'Home', icon: 'dashboard', class: '', children: [] },
  { path: '/photo', title: 'Photo', icon: 'person', class: '', children: [] },
  {
    path: '/admin', title: 'Admin', icon: 'library_books', class: '', children: [
      { path: '/person', title: 'Person List', icon: 'bubble_chart', class: '' },
      { path: '/setting', title: 'Setting', icon: 'bubble_chart', class: '' },

    ]
  }
];

@Component({
  selector: 'app-sidebar',
  templateUrl: './sidebar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sidebar.component.css']
})
export class SidebarComponent implements OnInit {
  menuItems: any[];

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.menuItems = ROUTES.filter(menuItem => menuItem);

  }
}
```

Comment: There is no code for a submenu in your ngFor. It will only create the toplevel menu items

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Angular's `*ngIf` directive to toggle the submenus visibility when the Admin menu item is clicked.

HTML to include the children sub-menu items,

```
<li routerLinkActive="active" *ngFor="let menuItem of menuItems" class="{{menuItem.class}} nav-item">
  <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="[menuItem.path]" (click)="menuItem.open = !menuItem.open">
    <i class="material-icons">{{menuItem.icon}}</i>
    <p>{{menuItem.title}}</p>
  </a>
  <div *ngIf="menuItem.children && menuItem.open">
    <ul>
      <li *ngFor="let child of menuItem.children">
        <a [routerLink]="[menuItem.path + child.path]">{{child.title}}</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</li>
```

`RouteInfo` interface to include an `'open'` attribute,

```
declare interface RouteInfo {
  path: string;
  title: string;
  icon: string;
  class: string;
  children: any;
  open?: boolean; 
}
```

`'ROUTES'` data setting `'open'` to false by default for the Admin menu,

```
export const ROUTES: RouteInfo[] = [
  { path: '/home', title: 'Home', icon: 'dashboard', class: '', children: [] },
  { path: '/photo', title: 'Photo', icon: 'person', class: '', children: [] },
  {
    path: '/admin', title: 'Admin', icon: 'library_books', class: '', open: false, children: [
      { path: '/person', title: 'Person List', icon: 'bubble_chart', class: '' },
      { path: '/setting', title: 'Setting', icon: 'bubble_chart', class: '' },
    ]
  }
];
```

Submenus of Admin should be hidden initially and should be shown when you click on the Admin menu. Also don't forget to append parent path to child path in `[routerLink]`.